# Is it faster to have four times 2 GB or two times 4 GB of RAM with a dual-channel mainboard?

Tags: memory, performance

I'm building a Core [i7-860](http://ark.intel.com/products/41316) system which supports dual-channel memory (up to 16 GB in four DIMMs), my target is 8 GB. From the performance perspective, is it better to have two times 4 GB or four times 2 GB?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Four sticks would cause more strain on the memory controller and motherboard chipset. It would take slightly longer for the CPU to add and retrieve data from four sticks as opposed to two.

For this reason, 2 x 4 GB would be faster then 4 x 2 GB.

**EDIT** - there is [a much better technical explanation](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Hardware/Components/Memory/Q_24148760.html?sfQueryTermInfo=1+2+4+ram+stick#a23656844) on [The Hyphenated Site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) to enforce my answer, although it does mention lower sized sticks:

> It's better to use two 2 GB modules --
>   not for any appreciable speed
>   difference (although there may be a
>   small advantage -- more in a bit) --
>   but for a more reliable memory
>   subsystem.
>
> Most desktop systems use unbuffered
>   RAM modules -- this results in very
>   large loads on the address and data
>   buses when you have more than two
>   modules installed, and can
>   significantly degrade the signalling
>   on these buses. The memory subsystem
>   "sees' one load per memory chip -- so
>   with two modules installed, that's up to
>   32 loads (with double-sided modules)
>   ... and with four modules installed
>   that's as many as 64 electrical loads
>   on the bus. Some systems
>   automatically adjust for this higher
>   load by either increasing the voltage
>   a small amount; reducing the clock
>   frequency of the memory (thus slightly
>   slowing it down); or by adding a cycle
>   to the SPD's latency setting (again,
>   slightly slowing it down).   These
>   adjustments help keep the memory
>   subsystem reliable -- but mean that 4
>   x 1 GB modules would be slightly slower
>   than 2 x 2 GB modules on these systems.
>   But regardless of whether there's any
>   timing differences, the memory will
>   definitely be more reliable with only
>   two modules.

Credit to garycase at The Hyphenated Site for this answer.

Comment: Intuitively, I would think that what Joe Taylor says might be true (4x2GB leaving more room for concurrent work) but I may be completely wrong.

But the difference will be probably small anyway, I'll probably go for 2x4GB as this will allow an upgrade to 16GB in the future if needed.

Comment: are any of those user application benchmarks, or are they all synthetic tests?  If the former I'd like a link to them.

Comment: I removed my *comment* above as I have completely failed at finding the article I was reading at work earlier. My answer remains exactly the same, although I have additionally backed it up with a much better technical explanation than mine.

Comment: It might make more sense to link to the corsair presentation garycase cites instead of EE directly since without paying you have to jump through a google hoop to see EE content.

Comment: It would be nice to know *how much* slower four memory modules would be. I know that a precise figure will be hard to come by, but are we talking about 0.1%? 1%? 10%?

Answer (score 18):

2x4GB will be slightly faster in benchmarks because the motherboard has to relax timings slightly to handle two DIMMs per channel but in real world use you'll never notice a difference.  It also can matter if you're overclocking significantly where the second set of DIMMs will limit your ability to push the memory clocks quite as high.

If costs are about the same, 2x4 GB will give you room to expand to 16 GB of memory in the future if you need it.  If costs are significantly higher and you don't anticipate needing more RAM, there's no reason not to save money and use 4x2GB instead.

Comment: The price of 2x4GB is slightly higher than 4x2GB, however, I also value the possibility to upgrade to 16GB in the future so I'll probably go for that.

Answer (score 6):

Not my answer but the one that I followed:

This question has come up before in several other forums, but there has never been a good clear answer. Overclocking, upgradability, and temperature aside, I would suspect that 4x2 would be slightly faster than 2x4 because there would be more interleaving. Interleaving means that the data is spread out across more memory chips. While some chips are waiting for their CAS timing cycle to complete, data access can occur from the other chips.

The thing is, it really depends on the [northbridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_%28computing%29) (NB) implementation. The NB must be able to take advantage of interleaving across four DIMMs, and I don't know which NBs do and which don't. I suspect the most of the Xeon NBs can interleave across four DIMMs, in fact most of those NBs require DIMMs to be installed in groups of four. I'm not sure about the consumer NB lines such as P35, 965, and nForce 680i, the answer could be different for each chipset...

I know this does not directly answer your question. I am quite certain that 4x2 will never be slower than 2x4, it will either be the same or faster if the NB supports four-way interleave.

Comment: The only benchmark I can find (on the old AMD 939) showed performance slowing as a result of the second bank being populated due to the timing hit.  It's possible old controllers (or FBRAM controllers on servers) did benefit that way but newer consumer controller do not.

http://www.anandtech.com/memory/showdoc.aspx?i=2560&p=2