# How to decide the RAM for new laptops

Tags: laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to have four times 2 GB or two times 4 GB of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/110031/is-it-better-to-have-four-times-2-gb-or-two-times-4-gb-of-ram)

I am planing to buy a new dell latitude laptop. With 4 GB of RAM size. But On their website there is option to choose the RAM. As following,

1. 4GB (1x4GB) 1333MHz DDR3 SDRAM
2. 4GB (2x2GB) 1333MHz DDR3 SDRAM

What factors should I have in mind on deciding from these options? What should be best option to choose in your point?

Comment: While the linked question talks about 2*4 and 4*2 GB, the same reasoning applies, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, they let you choose whether you want two 2 GB modules or one 4 GB module. Generally speaking, if you use less modules, your power consumption will be a bit lower, but larger modules tend to be a bit more expensive.

Oh, and of course, choosing a single 4 GB module will leave one memory slot free in case you ever want to expand your RAM.

Comment: I would add that using two modules in dual-channel mode has only marginal influence on the overall system speed and given the ever increasing memory requirements, it might be wiser to go with the one memory module option and later expand the memory to 8 GiB.